# Upload PDF file to Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload the file below to my Google Drive with Javascript, and using the [Google Developer's](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-js) example. The file is created on the fly by a user selection process, then auto-downloaded to default dir (downloads). Is there a way to place the file on Google Drive at the same time? I am using jsPDF and have tried a few things like below but not successful.

```
E:\Downloads\MyFile.pdf
```

I am bypassing the file picker as I know which file to upload. I have modified the Google example to pass the code the file name but it is failing.

I think I need to create a Blob of the file on my HDD to then pass to the Google API but I have tried a few combinations without success. Any help is appreciated.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var CLIENT_ID = 'my-client-id';
      var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';
      var FOLDER_ID = 'my-drive-folder-id';

      /**
       * Called when the client library is loaded to start the auth flow.
       */
      function handleClientLoad() {
        window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
      }

      /**
       * Check if the current user has authorized the application.
       */
      function checkAuth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize(
            {'client_id': CLIENT_ID, 'scope': SCOPES, 'immediate': true},
            handleAuthResult);
      }

      /**
       * Called when authorization server replies.
       *
       * @param {Object} authResult Authorization result.
       */
      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
            var MyFile = "E:\PAPA\Downloads\test.pdf";
            insertFile(MyFile);
        }
      }

      /**
       * Start the file upload.
       *
       * @param {Object} evt Arguments from the file selector.
       */
      function uploadFile(evt) {
        gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {
          var file = evt.target.files[0];
          insertFile(file);
        });
      }

      /**
       * Insert new file.
       *
       * @param {File} fileData File object to read data from.
       * @param {Function} callback Function to call when the request is complete.
       */
      function insertFile(fileData, callback) {
        const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
        const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
        const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);
        reader.onload = function(e) {
          var contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octet-stream';
          var metadata = {
            'title': fileData.name,
            'mimeType': contentType,
            'parents': [{"id":FOLDER_ID}]
          };

          var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
          var multipartRequestBody =
              delimiter +
              'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
              JSON.stringify(metadata) +
              delimiter +
              'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
              'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
              '\r\n' +
              base64Data +
              close_delim;

          var request = gapi.client.request({
              'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files/',
              'method': 'POST',
              'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
              'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
              },
              'body': multipartRequestBody});
          if (!callback) {
            callback = function(file) {
              console.log(file)
            };
          }
          request.execute(callback);
        }
      }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--Add a file picker for the user to start the upload process -->
    <input type="file" id="filePicker" style="display: none" />
    <input type="button" id="authorizeButton" style="display: none" value="Authorize" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am bypassing the file picker as I know which file to upload. I have modified the Google example to pass the code the file name but it is failing.

This is the problem.

A string containing a file name is not a file.

Browsers do not provide a means for web sites to read files from visitors' drives based on the file name (it would be a huge security hole).

Comment: Hi @Quentin, I understand. Is there a way to achieve this? The user creates the PDF based on selections made then it automatically downloads to the Downloads folder. Is there a way to place a copy on Google Drive at the same time?

Comment: If you're creating it client side, then possibly, but you'll have to use the data you are creating the PDF with to make a the file object and not the place then save it to. If you are creating it server side, then you'd have to sent it to Dropbox from the server side code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am creating it client side with jsPDF then saving it on local HDD. So create the file object prior to saving the file? How to search for examples on this? Thansk!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob possibly. It isn't something I've done.

Answer (score 0):

You could integrate with the Save to Drive button: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/savetodrive

Then you don't have to worry about the extra redirect via their local downloads folder.